# My ProtectedRoute Page cant work react router dom v6 above

Tags: reactjs, authentication, routes, react-router-dom

#Ask
in my exercise im trying to implement protected route in my react project. but im still confused with updated react router dom in version 6 above from route. when user logout then if user access profile must redirect to login page. but its not. maybe everyone can help me. im still find the problem right now. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H6BPS.png)[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lCKQe.png)

```html
<Router>
    <div className="App">
      <Header/>
      <div className="container container-fluid">
        <Routes>
          <Route path="/" element={<Home/>} exact />
          <Route path="/search/:keyword" element={<Home/>}/>
          <Route path="/product/:id" element={<ProductDetails/>} exact />

          <Route path="/login" element={<Login/>}/>
          <Route path="/register" element={<Register/>}/>            
          <Route path='/me' element={<ProtectedRoute>
              <Profile/>
          </ProtectedRoute>} exact/>
        </Routes>
      </div>
      <Footer/>
    </div>
    </Router>
```

and this is my protectedroute page

```html
import React, { Fragment } from "react";
import { Outlet, Navigate } from 'react-router-dom'
import { useSelector } from "react-redux";

    const ProtectedRoute = ({ component: Component, ...rest }) => {

    const { isAuthenticated, loading } = useSelector(state => state.auth)

  return (
    <Fragment>
        {loading === false && (
            <Outlet
                {...rest}
                render={props => {
                    if(isAuthenticated === false) {
                        return <Navigate to='/login' />
                    }                    

                    return <Component {...props} />
                }}
            />
        )}
    </Fragment>
  );
};

export default ProtectedRoute;
```

do you have same experience ? please help. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Private route:

```
import React from 'react';
import { useLocation, Navigate } from 'react-router-dom';
//routes
//replace the following with your own url
import { getLoginPageUrl } from '../routingConstants/AppUrls';

const PrivateRoute = ({ children }) => {
    const location = useLocation();

    //to be revised
    if (localStorage.getItem('token')) {
        return children;
    }

    return <Navigate replace to={getLoginPageUrl()} state={{ from: location }} />;
};

export default PrivateRoute;
```

Usage:

```
<Routes>
        <Route
            path="/profil"
            element={
                <PrivateRoute>
                    <ProfilePage />
                </PrivateRoute>
            }
        />
</Routes>
```

Comment: i guess from route its already same with my code. But im still dont get solution. Sorry Mr.adam

Comment: Have a look at the following working code example: (https://github.com/react-custom-projects/react-router-v6 )

Comment: i guest it works. but im getting error from my code. thanks

Comment: im trouble in my profile page. its not redirect to login page because user unlogin

Comment: Can you vote up to my answer if it's solving the issue of redirecting please?

Comment: im sorry mr.adam. i will vote once my problem solve. but it still get error